# Unable to establish secure connection with the server (while on said server)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, web-config, ldap, server

I'm using active directory in my MVC application.  While running locally everything works like a charm - login, logout, etc.

However, when I publish my application out to it's own server, it starts throwing this error.  It is on the same server it is trying to connect to - and I have no idea how to fix this.  Other solutions previously suggested adding connectionUsername and connectionPassword (which I did since I had the same issues running locally earlier), so I know these are valid connection criteria.

Here is my current connection info...

```
    ...
    <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://mysite.com/DC=MS,DC=SRV"  />
    ...

    ...
    <trust level="Full" />
    ...

    ...
    <authentication mode="Windows">
          <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" 
                 timeout="45" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All" />
      </authentication>
      <membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
          <providers>
              <clear />
              <add name="ADMembershipProvider" connectionUsername="myUser"  
                   connectionPassword="myPW" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" 
                   connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
          </providers>
      </membership>
      ...
```

Any help is appreciated. I can't think of a reason why I'd have security issues when connecting to the server the website is currently running on.

Comment: If you're using AD, is there a reason you can't just set Windows Authentication in IIS and remove the forms login?  (I may be missing something, so genuine question)

Comment: You should look at the cas level I think it needs to be set to full for an MVC app

Comment: @freedomn-m honestly I have never done any AD login stuff before, so I was just following the tutorials I was finding.   I'm not sure how to go about removing the forms login while still allowing for users to login? I didn't see anything like that when I was doing my research.

Comment: @BillRuhl I'll edit this in, but I do already have <trust level="Full" /> in my web.config, if that's what you're mentioning. Otherwise - what do you mean by 'cas' level?

Comment: Change your authentication to just `<authentication mode="Windows" />` and remove `<membership>`, then, in IIS, open your site and select *Authentication* - you should see 'Forms' *enabled* - disable this and look for 'Windows Authentication' and enable that - only Windows Authentication should be enabled, nothing else (ie not Anonymous and not Forms).  If you see Forms+Anonymous but no Windows, it's not installed.  GC/FF may prompt the user for their windows login once - IE will by default auto login (no prompt) - option is Security-Local Intranet-Custom-User Authentication-Automatic Logon

Comment: @freedomn-m I appreciate the explanation - but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.  Everything loads fine but it's not letting me login (tried normal server accounts, tried my AD login with DOMAIN\username).  Is there any mapping I need to do for which users are allowed to log in to this website?

Comment: Try changing your cn string to `connectionString="LDAP://mydc.mysite.com/DC=MS,DC=SRV` replacing mydc with an actual domain controller.